# How to change height, width units globally in React Native

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

It's a fairly large React Native app, and all the units used in this app are in DP. This is why it's not scaling properly on iPads and tablets. Now, I want to replace the DP value with a value calculated based on the device width and height. These specifics seem to be too difficult to target using regex properly, so I can't automate this. Is there any interceptor, hook, or any other methods where I can get these values and change them?

Answer (score 1):

You are probably searching for this: [React Native Extended StyleSheet](https://github.com/vitalets/react-native-extended-stylesheet)

Using this library you have to calculate the `rem` or the dynamic scaling factor on the root of the project and then export it and use them in the stylesheet as string values. This might solve this problem. This will make the styles responsive and the values you calculate in the main container would be depending on the device height and width.

Comment: I'm already using it. The problem is I have to change the values for all components manually. Looking for a way to automate this.

Comment: @ShakilAhmed This would only be possible if you have made the values of style globally and used that global values everywhere. Then changing that global value would reflect everywhere else I am afraid you have to do that manually.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Is there any way to hook into the 'Stylesheet' import and change values there. I think the 'create' method takes the object and does some operations before sending it over the bridge. Looking for ideas.

Comment: I don't think so. You have to hook inside each of the stylesheet object in every screen which I don't think would be possible. Still, if you define them globally and then use them might solve the issue for future if you need to twick again.